# webpack: Unexpected character '@' loading css file

Tags: javascript, webpack, semantic-ui

I am trying to get working with semantic-ui in a react component I am making for distribution. but webpack is giving me trouble, I have never had to mess around with it too much thanks to tools like `create-react-app` so I don't know how to troubleshoot this...

Here is my webpack config...

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2', // THIS IS THE MOST IMPORTANT LINE! :mindblow: I wasted
    // more than 2 days until realize this was the line most important in all this guide.
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|build)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['env'],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  externals: {
    react: 'commonjs react', // this line is just to use the React dependency of our
    // parent-testing-project instead of using our own React.
  },
};
```

Any ideas what to add to it? or is there a plugin that will do the adding for me?

#### EDIT (added information):

the error must be from this file though because it happened right after importing the css as directed by the [semantic UI docs](https://react.semantic-ui.com/usage#semantic-ui-package)

the line in the css file (according to the webpack error is a font include)

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/cssfamily=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic&subset=latin);/
```

Comment: can you show the css file?

Comment: Also posting index.html would be useful. The error is not from this file.

Comment: @brk I added the line the error is coming from according to webpack, it is a huge minified css file

Comment: @NicolaeS I didn't add any `link` tags in the index.html because the instructions didn't say anything about that other than importing the module from the `index.js` file

Comment: @deltaskelta if you want to include the CSS file in index.js it looks like you're missing a CSS loader for webpack. Did you trying adding this to the config?
`module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
      }
    ]
  }
}`

Source: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader

Comment: I added that and now I am getting a different error... `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style-loader' in '/Users/Jeff/javascript/react-awesome'`

Comment: Try running `npm install --save-dev css-loader` in your app

Comment: @NicolaeS I installed those two loaders and I got errors saying I needed a bunch more loaders. Is there a way to autoload necessary loaders?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155657/discussion-between-nicolaes-and-deltaskelta).

Answer (score -1):

I would remove the import from CSS and place it classically in the index.html file with

```
<!-- your index.html <head> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/cssfamily=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic&subset=latin" />
```

Also, if nothing works in the current setup and I don't understand why - I will get it solved by trying another tutorial 9 out of 10 times.

However, if you're very keen on carrying this on - I suggest putting everything in a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/) or a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com) to give everybody a bit more context.

Comment: can you then point me to another semantic ui tutorial, outside of the official guide which was posted in my question, which may solve this problem?

Comment: Hey @deltaskelta - not sure if I can find a tutorial, but did you try adding the <link> to index.html directly?

Comment: IMO, I wasnt meamt to grep a minified css file to remove a single line and manually add link the source in am HTML file. im not saying it wont work, but it is definitely a hack